# Display emojis stored in Algolia

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, emoji, algolia

I am using Algolia to do autocomplete on cities around the world. I want to display the emoji flag for the country that it's in alongside it in suggested results, however when trying to add the flags in the algolia dashboard it turns them into little diamonds etc. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather add the flag at display time, instead of indexing the emoji in Algolia (the small diamonds you're seeing is a limitation of Algolia's emoji highlighting).

```
templates: {
  suggestion: function(suggestion) {
    return '<i class="flag ' + suggestion.countryCode + '"></i> ' +
      suggestion._highlightResult.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular library for getting the flags you would suggest? @redox

Comment: I used https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css in the past @dylankbuckley

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @redox